# Not mounted volume taking space and not visible in diskutil

Tags: macos, disk-utility, big-sur

I had a duplicate "Macintosh HD - Data" volume from a reinstallation, which I deleted via "Delete APFS Volume..." in the Disk Utility application.
Now the volume is gone, but the space seems to be still taken by it.

Disk Utility shows 1 Not Mounted volume with 132 GB:
[image: disk utility screenshot]

When running `diskutil list` this not mounted volume doesn't show up:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     45.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 282.7 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                652.6 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            22.7 GB    disk1s7
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 22.7 GB    disk1s7s1
```

With the volume not showing up, I wasn't able to find any solution for it.
How do I get the space back?

Comment: I hope you deleted the right volume!! I notice the deleted one is bigger than the one you kept. Do a backup and reboot.

Comment: @Gilby I did a TM backup and verified the mounted path before deleting it. I already did multiple reboots, and it was the correct one.